# Writing ARMv7 instructions

Tags: assembly, arm

I've been working on this problem without much luck.

A single precision IEEE 754 number is stored in memory at address X. Write a
sequence of ARM instructions to multiply the number at X by 16 and store the result back
at X. You must accomplish this without using any floating-point instructions (you may
ignore overflow or underflow).

This is what I have so far.

```
ENTRY ;The first instruction from where execution begins
start
MOV r0,754 ;stores 754 in r0 register
MOV r1,16 ;store 16 in r1
MUL r0,r0,r1 ;r0=r0+r1

stop
MOV r0, #0x18 ; report exception mechanism
LDR r1, =0x20026 ; ApplicationExit
SVC #0x123456 ; SWI
END ; Mark end of file.
```

I'm supposed to test this code in ARMSIM which uses ARMv7.  This code will not run in it unfortunately.

I new to assembly language so I don't what I'm doing wrong.  ARMSIM just crashes when I try to load the code.

Comment: armsim is arm7 not armv7 correct?  But your code is pretty generic, what if you try a simple program that just performs the svc exit or an infinite loop or something like that.  What have you tried that works?

Comment: ARMSim is based on the ARM7TDMI processor.
ARM7TDMI uses an implementation of the ARMv4T architecture.

Comment: Are you able to successfully load a simple program without the mov & mul instructions?